# help me in trace of following proposition

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

In a paper an author proved the following proposition

Please help me in  trace proof of following proposition

Proposition: let $f$ be a homeomorphism of  a connected topological manifold $M$ with fixed point set $F$. then either $(1)$
$f$ is invariant on each component of $M-F$ or $(2)$  there are exactly two component  and $f$ interchanges them.

and after that he said:

In the case of $(2)$ the above argument shows that F cannot contain an open set and
hence $dim F\leq (dim M) -1$ and  since $F$ separates $M$ we have $dim F = (dim M) -1$.
G. Bredon  has shown that if $M$ is also orientable
then any involution with an odd codimensional fixed point set must reverse the
orientation; hence we obtain

Let $f$ be an orientation-preserving homemorphism of an orientable
manifold $M$; then $f$ is invariant on each component of $M-F$.

Can you say me, what does mean the dim $F$ here? Is always $F$ is sub manifold with above condition?
and how can we deduce that $dim F = n-1$?

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, here is a sketch that $F$ is a submanifold under the assumption that the group $G$ acting on $M$ is finite:

Consider the map $M \to \prod_{g \in G} M, m \mapsto (gm)_{g \in G}$. This is smooth and should be a local homeomorphism, hence its regular. The diagonal $\{(m,\ldots,m) | m \in M\}$ of the product is a submanifold, hence its preimage is a submanifold of $M$ and the preimage is exactly the fixed point a set.

For the second question, we have that $M$ is connected but $M - F$, with $F$ being a submanifold is not connected. Intuitively it is clear that a submanifold dividing a manifold into connected components must have codimension 1 but I cannot think of a proof right now. Maybe one could work with path-connectedness?

Comment: tahnk you so much

Comment: Excuse me, I have not understand your argument yet. in your argument you said the above map is local homeomorphism, it can not be happen, because the co domain has greater dim than domain. furthermore,  what is the meaning of regular for homeomorphism between topological manifold?

Comment: Ok you are right, my idea is just plainly wrong. I missed the point that we are talking about topological manifolds only, so the concept of regularity is not available. Do you have any conditions on your manifold or the group action or could you say which paper you are talking about?

Comment: Thank you so much for your taking time on my question.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer my question. I think we must solve this problem for involution between topological manifold. I know the solution for the smooth (involution) case. this problem is in the following paper     "M. Brown and J.M. Kister, Invariance of complementary domains of a fixed point set, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 91, No 3, (1984), 503-504."